# How do I get the ng-show to work inside an AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-show

I'm having trouble getting `ng-show` to work inside my directive template. I'm using AngularJS 1.6.4. The Chrome debugger shows the successful change from `ng-show="true"` to `ng-show="false"` in the final DOM. But the element stays hidden when set to true. It appears this is because AngularJS adds a `ng-hide` class to the list in the element, but does not remove this when `ng-show` changes to true. Maybe AngularJS does not evaluate at this stage? How do I get this to show/hide properly?

I've been playing around with this for a while and have tried may different approaches including using the `loading` parameter directly instead of using the scoped `showspinner`. I've also tried omitting the mustaches (AngularJS expression) in the directive template like so: `ng-show="showspinner"` but this makes it worse by just rendering to `ng-show="showspinner"` instead of `ng-show="false"`.

Following is my code.

The `$ctrl.result` is loaded asynchronously while the `$ctrl.resultsLoading` is set to `true`, when the results are done loading it's set to `false`:

```
<report-tile
     title="My Report Item"
     value="{{$ctrl.result.count|number:0}}"
     loading="{{$ctrl.resultsLoading}}">
</report-tile>
```

This is my ReportTileDirective.js

```
(function(angular) {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("app")
    .directive(
        "reportTile", 
        ["$templateCache", "$compile" ,function($templateCache, $compile) {
            return {
                restrict: "EA",
                scope: {
                    title: "@",
                    value: "@",
                    loading: "@"
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attribues) {
                    scope.showspinner = false;
                    scope.$watch("loading",
                        function () {
                            scope.showspinner = attribues.loading;
                            console.log("watching::loading::" + attribues.loading);

                        });
                },
                templateUrl: "app/directives/ReportTileDirective.html"
            };
        }]);
}(window.angular));
```

This is my ReportTileDirective.html

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-padding">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading tile-title">
        <strong>{{title === '' ? 'Loading' : title}}</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: right">
        <strong>
            <i ng-show="{{showspinner}}" class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
            {{value === '' ? 0 : value}}
        </strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally this is the rendered DOM (as shown in the Chrome debugger Elements tab) when loading is done and it switches to `true`, the `ng-hide` is not removed:

```
<i ng-show="true" class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin ng-hide"></i>
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Directive scope variable not working with ng-show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217353/directive-scope-variable-not-working-with-ng-show)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my question is a duplicate of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217353/directive-scope-variable-not-working-with-ng-show?rq=1) and thanks to @CodeWarrior's answer I was able to fix this. I can remove the whole `link:` section and use the `loading` parameter directly if: I bind it with `=` instead of `@` and then get rid of the expression syntax, so that this is evaluated in the directive rather than beforehand.

So my directive usage changes to:

```
<report-tile
    title="My Report Item"
    value="{{$ctrl.result.count|number:0}}"
    loading="$ctrl.resultsLoading"> <!-- notice no mustaches here -->
</report-tile>
```

and my directive JavaScript file changes to:

```
(function(angular) {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("app")
    .directive(
        "reportTile", 
        ["$templateCache", "$compile" ,function($templateCache, $compile) {
            return {
                restrict: "EA",
                scope: {
                    title: "@",
                    value: "@",
                    loading: "=" /* notice the = binding */
                },
                templateUrl: "app/directives/ReportTileDirective.html"
            };
        }]);
}(window.angular));
```

Then finally my directive template changes to:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-padding">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading tile-title">
        <strong>{{title === '' ? 'Loading' : title}}</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: right">
        <strong>
            <i ng-show="loading" class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> <!-- notice to mustaches here -->
            {{value === '' ? 0 : value}}
        </strong>
    </div>
</div>
```